# Weird spotlight issue

Tags: spotlight

For whatever reason, when I launch spotlight, type in "1", "1", "2", spotlight closes automatically.  Does anyone else have this issue?

Running 10.12.6 (16G1510) on a 2015 Macbook Pro

Comment: nope, just tried "1", "1", "2",  and 112  it stay on

Comment: Not sure if there is a connection, but 112 is an emergency phone number in India and the European Union.

Comment: Does it happen only with "112" or also with other input?

Comment: same behaviour if I search for "src" but not for "112"